# How to insert and right-align text that is not of the default font size?

Tags: text-properties

How to insert and right-align text that is not of the default font size?

This doesn't work:

```lisp
(let* ((text "abcd")
       (len (length text)))
  (insert
   "\n"
   (propertize " " 'display `((height 0.5) (space :align-to (- right (,len . width)))))
   (propertize "12345" 'font-lock-face 'error 'display '(height 0.5))
  "\n"))
```

Comment: It doesn't line up on the right side. It's outside the visible space.

Comment: Have you tried to run the code in the *scratch* buffer? Is `12345` on the right side of the screen at you?

Comment: If you don't take all information I put into the question, how can you rate, if there's something missing? Might the part you are ignoring be the missing piece?

Answer (score 1):

The example in the question works fine. There's a bug in Emacs 27.1 that makes it fail. See the discussion on the mailing list: [Why is `(1 . width)` zero?](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2021-01/msg00349.html).